# Which autoresizing masks must I use within a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

From the docs of UITabBarController:

> If the root view controller is a
>   navigation controller, the tab bar
>   controller makes further adjustments
>   to the size of the displayed
>   navigation content so that it does not
>   overlap the tab bar. Any views you
>   display in a tab bar interface should
>   therefore have their autoresizingMask
>   property set to resize the view
>   appropriately under any conditions.

so, if I don't use any nibs, which autoresizing masks must I use here?

Comment: thanks for the edit ... suffered from auto-completion in safari...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`